# Joomla iphone template making

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

How to make an ordinary joomla site into a compatible mobile template when viewed from mobile

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the templating comes from working out what width of screen you're using (look for CSS Media queries), then it comes down to what mobiles (or screen widths) you want to support.

Comment: now I am using ICETHEME to develop the website and had completed almost 90% of its work. Now client needs to integrate the mobile version of the template, but it dont have a mobile version preset in it, so I know there would be a way to impliment it, if you could suggest a way to make this ice theme template also to a mobile version thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give me a link to the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try Mobile Joomla component (mobilejoomla.com)